# "attention heads" in seq2seq.embedding_attention_seq2seq of tensorflow

Tags: nlp, tensorflow

I'm new to the tensorflow and trying to implement the "seq2seq" model according to the tutorial. I'm not sure about one argument "num_heads" (default=1) of the func "embedding_attention_seq2seq". What does it represent? I didn't find it in the related papers.

Answer (score 1):

Had you read the source code of any decoder like [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L648) you would get to know that it represents the number of attentions.

Sometimes there are several attentions(hierarchical attentions), for instance this one(as depicted bellow) in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06023).
TL;DR; the first one is for the word and the second one is for the sentence.
 Please check this graph: 
[image]

Comment: Is that how many attention vectors we calculated for one unit in the decoder?  
How to change the number of attentions? Is that like we run over encoder states twice?

Comment: Yes, you can verify those in the following code, especially [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L683).

Comment: yes. But I have this problem.If we have two attentions what will happen?

Comment: Perfect. So if we have 2 heads it will calculate attention with two different weight set in-order to capture more information. In some papers I'v seen that calculating attention with different hidden layers in the encoder.Since here attention head parameter is not specifically mentioned I think this is about calculating the attention with two parameters sets.